# Is it possible to mimic the template argument deduction of nested initializer_lists with variadic templates?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, c++20

I have an N-dimensional vector class `ndvector` with the following constructors (definitions excluded):

```cpp
template <typename T> class ndvector {
public:
  constexpr ndvector(std::initializer_list<T> il);

  constexpr ndvector(std::initializer_list<ndvector<T>> il);
};
```

These constructors allow for the initialization of `ndvectors` of any dimension:

```cpp
ndvector a{1, 2};

ndvector b{a, {3, 4}};
ndvector<int> c{{1, 2}, {3, 4}};

ndvector d{b, {a, {3, 4}}};
ndvector<int> e{{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}};
```

For a reason I don't fully understand, `T` must be explicitly specified in some cases, but that is a small price to pay.

That being said, I ran into some issues while attempting to achieve similar functionality with a statically-allocated `ndarray` class:

```cpp
template <typename T, std::size_t... DIMS> class ndarray;

template <typename T, std::size_t DIM, std::size_t... DIMS>
class ndarray<T, DIM, DIMS...> {
public:
  template <typename... Ts>
  constexpr ndarray(Ts &&...elements);

  template <std::convertible_to<ndarray<T, DIMS...>>... Ts>
  constexpr ndarray(Ts &&...elements);
};

template <typename T, std::same_as<T>... Ts>
ndarray(T, Ts...) -> ndarray<T, 1 + sizeof...(Ts)>;

template <typename T, std::same_as<T>... Ts, std::size_t... DIMS>
ndarray(ndarray<T, DIMS...>, ndarray<Ts, DIMS...>...)
    -> ndarray<T, 1 + sizeof...(Ts), DIMS...>;
```

Even with explicit template arguments, the last line in the snippet below fails to compile:

```cpp
ndarray a{1, 2};
ndarray<int, 2> b{3, 4};

ndarray c{a, b};
ndarray<int, 2, 2> d{{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
```

(Note: at the time of writing, MSVC will encounter an internal compiler error for any instantiation of `ndarray` due to a [bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Internal-compiler-error-caused-by-self-r/1604455). I am using GCC 11, but GCC 10 and various versions of Clang also work).

As far as I am aware, this is because `{1, 2}`, etc. are treated as initializer lists that cannot be resolved to a type. Unfortunately, I cannot use `std::initializer_list` because they rarely form constant expressions, which would mean that `DIMS` could never be determined implicitly. I have also tried the following two constructors, to no avail:

```cpp
template <typename... Ts> requires (... || !std::convertible_to<Ts, ndarray<T, DIMS...>>)
constexpr ndarray(Ts &&...elements);

template<typename... Ts>
constexpr ndarray(const ndarray<Ts, DIMS...> &...elements) {}
```

```cpp
constexpr ndarray(const ndarray<T, DIMS...> elements...) {}
```

The first alternative fails for the same reason - `Ts` cannot be deduced from the untyped initializer list. C-style variadic arguments don't work either, as the first initializer list will seemingly attempt to initialize `elements`. Is there another approach that could bear more fruit?

Comment: `{..}` has no type, and so limit deduction to `T(&)[N]` or `std::initializer_list<T>`. So cannot be used with forwarding reference.

Answer (score 0):

Whereas I don't think there is a solution for CTAD and `{..}`, you might turn your class to have exactly expected number of parameters instead of using forwarding reference, something like:

```
// Helper to have fixed type when folding std::index_sequence<Is...>
template <std::size_t, typename T> using always_t = T;

template <typename T, typename... Seqs>
struct ndarray_impl;

template <typename T>
struct ndarray_impl<T>
{
    ndarray_impl(const T& data) : data(data) {}

    T data;
};

template <typename T, std::size_t... Is, typename... Seqs>
struct ndarray_impl<T, std::index_sequence<Is...>, Seqs...>
{
    ndarray_impl(const always_t<Is, ndarray_impl<T, Seqs...>>&... args) : data{args...} {}

    std::array<ndarray_impl<T, Seqs...>, sizeof... (Is)> data;
};

template <typename T, std::size_t... Is>
using ndarray = ndarray_impl<T, std::make_index_sequence<Is>...>;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d0534fbe5f757862)